# How to enable docker in VS2022 Community

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio-2022

I am using VS2022 Community and attempting to get Docker enabled.  Docker is installed on my Windows 10 Desktop.  The docs say to download and install the Docker extension, but the extension doesn't show up in a search in VS or from the Microsoft Marketplace web page.  What am I missing?